# Where can I find a projector case which is compatible with the iphone 5?

Tags: iphone, compatibility, case, projector

I've managed to [locate](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005Y6DROG) [numerous](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0097570OS) [cases](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008IFYWAS) which are what I'm looking for but none are available for the Iphone 5 model. I have an adapter cord but obviously that defeats the purpose of having the device be a case.

Is such a case in production currently? When can I expect one to come into production?

Answer (score 1):

http://dx.com/p/a50p-2-in-1-pico-projector-battery-pack-for-iphone-5-ipad-mini-samsung-galaxy-s2-black-201546

I have ordered many items from DealExtreme so far and I am overall satisfied with the quality-price and their great support and after sales team. You can trust.

Comment: Well that's not really what I was looking for, it's not a case.